# How do I get only a specific part of a cell in Excel or Numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to extract data of transactions into useful separate cells. Right now I can have in Excel or Numbers (on OS X) a cell such as:

`04/23 SUPERMARKET STORE $38.89`

However, I want to split this up into separate cells for the date (everything before the first space), the transaction details (everything after the first space before the last space, or alternatively before the dollar sign), and a third cell that has everything after the last space or after the dollar sign. However, I'm not sure what formula to use to extract this data.

In Numbers at least, I already know I can find which character is the first space and which is the dollar sign with a function like `FIND("$",B2,1)` and it will return "25" for example. I don't know if this is a starting point though and what to do with that, if I can request every character in a string starting with the 32nd character for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first part `=LEFT(E5,FIND(" ",E5)-1)`

middle part `=MID(E5,FIND(" ",E5)+1,FIND("$",E5)-1-FIND(" ",E5)-1)`

last part `=RIGHT(E5,LEN(E5)-(FIND("$",E5)-1))`

Replace E5 with your cell's ref.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but may be helpful for someone- I would use text to column on this one. Select Text to column wizard and move through the steps.

Step 1: Fixed Width

Step 2: Select the breaks, if you want to keep the date in the same format, "04/23," hit Next

Step 3: Highlight the date column and select "Text" from the Column Data Format. Then hit Finish